# Filtering excel rows in hidden mode (VB Code)

Tags: excel, filter, find

I want to filter an extensive range of rows in Excel and copy their values without the filter running in Excel, only in VB code without visual action in Excel.
This procedure is very slow, I want a more agile alternative:

```
'
        xlSheet.Range("A1:Z100000").AutoFilter(1, "Criteria", , , False)

        xlSheet.Range("C1:F100000").Copy()

        xlSheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Paste:=XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Operation:=XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

        Application.CutCopyMode = CType(False, XlCutCopyMode)

        xlSheet.Range("A1:Z100000").AutoFilter(False)
'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks !

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Use ActiveX Data Object (ADO), see [Using ADO to Query an Excel Spreadsheet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx). 2) Use excel's advanced filter. 3) Determine rows count using COUNTIF(), redim resulting array, fill resulting array row by row, paste resulting array.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest this Code for the issue,,

Sub Exception_Review()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Dim FilterCriteria Dim CurrentsheetName As String Dim NewFileName As String 'Get the current sheets's name CurrentsheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 
Range("A2:K25").Select 
Selection.AutoFilter Selection.AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="No"  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select  Selection.Copy Worksheets.Add ActiveSheet.Name = "ExceptionReview"  Range("A1").Select 
ActiveSheet.Paste 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Cells.Select Selection.Columns.AutoFit Range("A1").Select (CurrentsheetName).Activate Selection.AutoFilter field:=1
 Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Select Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub

Comment: Your answer needs some formatting, otherwise its almost unreadable.

Comment: Feeling sorry for the inconvenience,, actually I've replied your query using my Cellphone,, probably it is the reason behind improper formating.